# ImagePickerController for iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to select a picture from the device's photo library.
This is my code so far. I am following a tutorial and that should work, but I am getting an error :

```
"Use of undeclared identifier info", on the second method, line 3.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
   - (IBAction)selectPicturePressed:(UIButton *)sender {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
    {
        UIImage *chosenImage  = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        self.imgToUpload.image = chosenImage;

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
```

Comment: The parameter is named `editInfo`.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you, and sorry for the stupid  question.

Comment: @rmaddy, now the image picker is shown, I can select a picture from it, but after dismissing it, the image is not shown in the imgToUpload view. Any clue?

Comment: 1) Replace `@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"` with `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`. You need to use the provided constant, not a string. 2) Do some debugging. Is `chosenImage` non-nil? Is `self.imgToUpload` non-nil?

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you again, I will try your proposal just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `info` to `editInfo` will resolve it.